# Refining My Instant Search Problems

Tags: php, jquery, search-engine

### Well, This Jquery script works great for getting my queries from the database and adding them on but I need it to work better than it does and I have scavenged the Internet with no luck.

--> How can I make it search based off not any letter in the word but by each letter I type in and all searches with exactly the same order of letters?

--> Also I want it to not show me all the queries when I type something in but only show the results after I begin typing so they are more accurate

--> One last thing (sorry) If I type something into the search bar and then remove it it leaves me with some random queries ?Help?

```
function searchq() {
var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
if($.trim(searchTxt) != '') {
$.post("search.php",{searchVal:searchTxt,}, function(output) {
            $("#output").html(output);
    });
    }
}



if(isset($_POST['searchVal'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['searchVal'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_\ -]/","",$searchq);
        
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE firstname LIKE '%$searchq%'  OR lastname LIKE '%$searchq%' ")  or die("Don't know why I could not search for you!");
        $count =  mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
            $output = 'There Were NO Such Results!';
            
        }else {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $fname = $row['firstname'];
                    $lname = $row['lastname'];
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    
                    $output .= '<div id="queryresult"><p><a href="#"> '.$fname.' </p></div>';
                }
        }
        }
        echo ($output);
```

Comment: the first question would seem to be a contradiction.

Comment: Didn't Know how to say it, I mean that I want it to search based off  of exactly what I type (Each letter in order) @Dagon

Comment: thats what it currently does. type **a** and the querry is run:   .. `LIKE '%a%'  OR lastname LIKE '%a%'`

Comment: @Dagon no I mean I want it to not pull up if for instance I typed the letter [a] into the input field I don't want [hail], [camping],and [elegant] as choices to come up I want [Aardvark],[American], and [Africa] to come up.

Comment: ok so you want to match the FIRST letter, change the query to: `LIKE 'a%'` just remove the wild card % from the start